# Vue Js select dropdown selected not working in my Edit form using Laravel 5.4

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5

Hi i have this vue js select dropdown. Now my problem is when i go to edit page then my select dropdown using Vue Js is not working it is not selected. My previous project works well in my current is not working. I use the same code. Here is my code below

my edit form views

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label>Time</label>
    <div id="app-time">
        <select name="time" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
            <option v-for="time in times" v-bind:value="time.value"
            :selected="time.value=={{json_encode($getDeliveryReceipt['time'])}}?true : false">
                @{{ time.text }}
            </option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

My vue js script

```
<script>
    //branch data
    new Vue({
    el: '#app-time',
        data: {
            times:[
                { text:'12:00 AM', value: '12:00 AM' },
                { text:'1:00 AM', value: '1:00 AM' },
                { text:'2:00 AM', value: '2:00 AM' },
                { text:'3:00 AM', value: '3:00 AM' },
                { text:'4:00 AM', value: '4:00 AM' },
                { text:'5:00 AM', value: '5:00 AM' },
                { text:'6:00 AM', value: '6:00 AM' },
                { text:'7:00 AM', value: '7:00 AM' },
                { text:'8:00 AM', value: '8:00 AM' },
                { text:'9:00 AM', value: '9:00 AM' },
                { text:'10:00 AM', value: '10:00 AM' },
                { text:'11:00 AM', value: '11:00 AM' },
                { text:'12:00 PM', value: '12:00 PM' },
                { text:'1:00 PM', value: '1:00 PM' },
                { text:'2:00 PM', value: '2:00 PM' },
                { text:'3:00 PM', value: '3:00 PM' },
                { text:'4:00 PM', value: '4:00 PM' },
                { text:'5:00 PM', value: '5:00 PM' },
                { text:'6:00 PM', value: '6:00 PM' },
                { text:'7:00 PM', value: '7:00 PM' },
                { text:'8:00 PM', value: '8:00 PM' },
                { text:'9:00 PM', value: '9:00 PM' },
                { text:'10:00 PM', value: '10:00 PM' },
                { text:'11:00 PM', value: '11:00 PM' }
            ]
        }
    })  
</script>
```

In my views i use this line of code in here

```
:selected="time.value=={{json_encode($getDeliveryReceipt['time'])}}?true : false"
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out? TIA. Any help is muchly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:selected` you need to use `v-model` on your select like this.

```
<div class="col-md-2">
    <label>Time</label>
    <div id="app-time">
        <select name="time" class="form-control" v-model="selectedValue">
            <option value="0">--Please Select--</option>
            <option v-for="time in times" :value="time.value">
                @{{ time.text }}
            </option>
        </select> 
    </div>
</div>
```

You can read more about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use json_encode method with double quoted string within interpolation, because it will generate string with enclosing in double quote.

```
echo json_encode('12:00 AM'); //"12:00 AM"
```

Use interpolation with single quote

```
<option v-for="time in times" 
  v-bind:value="time.value" 
  :selected="time.value == '{{$getDeliveryReceipt['time']}}'"
 >{{time.text}}</option>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-wqqydg?file=index.html

Comment: Check stackbitz link

Comment: Just made a change check again

Comment: you change it and it is not selected.

Comment: @PHPDev `{{ $getDeliveryReceipt['time'] }}` looks to me like a `.blade` variable. And I don't think you can use blade variables in your `.vue` files like this. You need to pass it as a prop from `.blade` to `.vue` file first and then use that variable like in my answer below

Comment: Im using Laravel 5.4 and Vue Js

Comment: The only thing you have to take care is make sure your PHP expression from blade template should print value without encoding it. `:selected="time.value == '4:00 PM'"`
check this expression in stackblitz. If directly supplies value to expression is working then your PHP expression should return same result.